# How to migrate my encrypted passwords to my new laptop

Tags: ssh, password, gpg, migration

I'm using `pass` to store my password. Passwords are stored in `~/.password-store`. This has been working for 10 years, but now I have a new laptop. I'm trying to migrate the passwords by copying what I think is required, but it does not work.

I copied the following directories to my new computer.

- `~/.password-store`
- `~/.ssh`
- `~/.gnupg`

Notice that I copied `.ssh` to get access to my GitHub repo. It is probably not related to `pass` but honestly I don't know. This approach does not work and `pass` tells me that there is no private key.

I tried to follow [the “Migrating Linux Pass
to a New Machine” tutorial](https://www.planetroast.com/migrating-linux-pass-to-new-machine),
but I was not able to figure out what to do at:

```
gpg --output private.pgp --armor --export-secret-key username@example
```

I don't know where `private.pgp` is supposed to be,
and I don't know what `username@example` is supposed to be
on my computer.

Alternative question: which files am I supposed to store in a safe place, in order to recover all my password in case my SDD would be irrecoverable? 
I've been praying for 10 years now for my SSD to not fail,
because if it does, I'll lose access to EVERYTHING. 
So far I prayed strong enough.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

So I eventually figured the problem myself (I think).

On my new computer there was already a `.gnupg` directory with one default file. I don't remember which one but anyway. When I copied my `.gnupg` folder from my old, to my new computer, I probably merged the two folders which mean the default file persisted and was not replaced by my old computer file. All other files were copied.

I copied again my `.gnupg` directory, paying attention to removing everything on my new computer, and it worked.